# Making a calendar view for iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to make a a month view Calendar for iPad like the one in iCal (or [this](http://itunes.apple.com/app/momagenda/id387027303?mt=8)).
I don't know how to get started. Can anyone provide some information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this : http://maniacdev.com/2011/09/tutorial-using-the-tapku-library-to-create-an-elegant-marked-calendar/

and here is the tutorial : http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need a big one. For displaying events each day. After some research I found AQGridView which I can use to add custom cells and use them.